# upload instagram image using instabot python

Tags: python, instagram

every time i try to upload image to instagram using instabot ,the uploading process success, but it's remove the source image and replace it with a file like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q5NS.png)

```
from instabot import Bot

insta = Bot()
insta.login(username = "******",password = "*******")
insta.upload_photo("69345262_164734494580851_8787380306948489225_n.jpg",caption ="just try")
```

what the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The image ist just renamed. You can name it back an that's it.